# Does eudemonia depend on tense?

Tags: time, happiness

Not asking about any particular concept of well being or happiness. The question may seem odd: if I am happy today now then I will have been happy for the day. But I suspect it at least may be more complex than that.

Does eudemonia depend on tense or does change only show us that our happiness can be unreal?

Comment: No. Colloquial "happiness" is a loose and inaccurate translation. *Eudaimonia*, on Aristotle's conception at least, is not about "feeling" happy or happiness-for-the-day, but something more objective, enduring and robust, see [SEP, Aristotle’s Ethics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-ethics/#HumaGoodFuncArgu):"*using reason well over the course of a full life is what happiness consists in... living well consists in activities caused by the rational soul in accordance with virtue or excellence*".

Comment: So we only have well being if we have it for out whole lives @Conifold ? If not, I see no reason to suppose that we cannot experience eudemonia for one day among many

Comment: Or do you think that eudemonia is only experienced as an abstraction away from life (I live well but never at any time)? Perhaps that's it

Comment: Eudaimonia is not something "experienced", it is a certain way of life that may or may not be accompanied by pleasurable experiences you are thinking of. Those emotional colorations are not eudaimonia, it is an objective state of affairs, and a persisting one by definition. To paraphrase Lao Zi, eudaimonia for a day is not the true eudaimonia.

Comment: I'm confused what mistake you think I've made @Conifold nowhere have I said that pleasure is sufficient for well being. Nor that well being for one day only is possible. And you haven't answered anything I've said. Annoying!

Comment: I just really dislike how you leave these long comments that seem to be correcting things I haven't said. I don't know if it's deliberate or not @Conifold either way, it's driven me away and sucks the fun out of the site for me at least. If you are just trying to clarify why the answer is "no" then you seem unable to show it yourself; get to the point!

Comment: Yes it's difficult to be happy when you're tense. /jk

Comment: This question is a deepity. That is, it is either totally shallow or totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your question uses both "eudaimoneia" and "happiness" as if they were interchangeable. But "happiness" has two meanings. One might be called "life satisfaction" and the other "affect-based", though neither of these terms is quite satisfactory. "Eudaimoneia" points firmly in direction of life satisfaction in an objective rather than a subjective sense; it is often translated as "being fortunate".

There are two issues here, but they interlock.

One is the issue between a concept of the good life that accepts that the good life depends on circumstances outside the agent's control and one that doesn't. Aristotle is firmly in the former camp. This is the issue of moral luck.

The other issue is whether eudaimoneia is a permanent, or at least life-long, state or whether it can be temporary. This seems to be the question you are asking.

Martha Nussbaum in her book "The Fragility of Goodness" argues that it can be temporary. Her argument is developed in the context of Ancient Greek philosophy and tragedy (which makes the book unusual in philosophical literature). She appeals to the tragedies, arguing that they show that people who are deeply committed to justice are vulnerable to external circumstances. She considers how far reason enables eudaimoneia to be independent of the chances of life and contrasts this view with Plato's idea that goodness is not affected by the circumstances that seem to threaten it.

The key issue, it seems to me, is whether eudaimoneia can be preserved in the face of an insoluble moral dilemma or not. If it can, it would seem that behaving well in such circumstances is enough. (But it may be impossible to pin down what "behaving well" is in such circumstances.) If it cannot, then eudaimoneia is not a question of what one deserves. This seems morally repugnant.

There is another issue relevant to this - whether eudaimoneia may be a question of balance over the whole of a life.

There is a review of "The Fragility of Goodness" at [The Fragility of Goodness. Luck and Ethics in Greek Tragedy and Philosophy. (Revised edition) – Bryn Mawr Classical Review](https://bmcr.brynmawr.edu/2002/2002.10.06)

There is a more general discussion of these issues at [Happiness (Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/happiness/#LifSatVerAffBasAcc)

Comment: Regarding "insoluble moral dilemmas", I don't think we have to insure all of our plans against potential trolley problems. Yes, hideous things go on all the time in this world, but maybe there are other ways of dealing with that beyond sheer goodness. Life survived the asteroid 65 million years ago, and I'm sure that was difficult.

Comment: Well, the point I was discussing was the question whether a life of moral goodness could ever come unstitched through cricumstances beyond the control of a good man. I thought the possibility of an insoluble moral dilemma argued that it could. Are you disagreeing with me? Or saying that there's no need to think about such things. (I don't like the trolley problem either. Would Agamemnon's dilemma between sacrificing his daughter or having his expedition of ships remain becalmed, without wind to propel them suit you better?)

Comment: I've experienced several really overwhelming things, starting at age 4, which basically took away all my choices and all I could do is survive. Can really bad overwhelming things disrupt your equanimity? Yes. Can equanimity and happiness be recovered? Also yes. The book of Job comes to mind.

Comment: Yes. That's why I rather incline to the view that one cannot judge eudaimoneia until the end of life. There a quotation from Solon (ancient greek poet and lawmaker) "Call no man happy until he is dead." And there's the rub.